# How to show the backslash commands in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, backslash, sqlcommand, backslash-commands

With `\help` or `\h` below, I could show the SQL commands as shown below:

```
\help
```

Or:

```
\h
```

```
postgres=# \help
Available help:
  ABORT                            CREATE USER
  ALTER AGGREGATE                  CREATE USER MAPPING
  ALTER COLLATION                  CREATE VIEW
  ALTER CONVERSION                 DEALLOCATE
  ALTER DATABASE                   DECLARE
  ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES         DELETE
  ALTER DOMAIN                     DISCARD
  ALTER EVENT TRIGGER              DO
  ALTER EXTENSION                  DROP ACCESS METHOD
  ALTER FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER       DROP AGGREGATE
  ALTER FOREIGN TABLE              DROP CAST
  ALTER FUNCTION                   DROP COLLATION
  ALTER GROUP                      DROP CONVERSION
  ALTER INDEX                      DROP DATABASE
  ALTER LANGUAGE                   DROP DOMAIN
...
```

Now, how can I show the backslash commands in PostgreSQL like `\l`, `\dt`, `\q`, `\h`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

With `\?` below, you can show the backslash commands in PostgreSQL as shown below:

```
\?
```

```
postgres=# \?
General
  \copyright             show PostgreSQL usage and distribution terms
  \crosstabview [COLUMNS] execute query and display results in crosstab
  \errverbose            show most recent error message at maximum verbosity
  \g [(OPTIONS)] [FILE]  execute query (and send results to file or |pipe);
                         \g with no arguments is equivalent to a semicolon
  \gdesc                 describe result of query, without executing it
  \gexec                 execute query, then execute each value in its result
  \gset [PREFIX]         execute query and store results in psql variables
  \gx [(OPTIONS)] [FILE] as \g, but forces expanded output mode
  \q                     quit psql
  \watch [SEC]           execute query every SEC seconds

Help
  \? [commands]          show help on backslash commands
  \? options             show help on psql command-line options
  \? variables           show help on special variables
  \h [NAME]              help on syntax of SQL commands, * for all commands
...
```